# Select names from a string using php

Tags: php

Hello I have the following  string and I want to keep only what is after `:`
here is my string :

```
/showname/88820665 : Jysk diner
/showname/88820666 : Sevecu
/showname/88820667 : Luminex Lightcares
/showname/88820668 : Pactius
/showname/88820669 : Aalborg Speciallaegeklinik
```

Comment: Just explode and collect the second part. `echo $part = explode(" : ", $str)[1]`... and son on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explode()

```
 $pieces = explode(":", $myString);

 echo $pieces[1];  // should contain  the right part of the string after :
```

In you have a single row string then

```
  $myRows= explode("\n", $myString);

  foreach( $myRows as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $value);
    echo $pieces[1]; 
  }
```

Comment: i did that but it selects also the 2nd row until the next `:` `Jysk diner
 /showname/88820666`

Comment: Is a single row string or are seperated rows ?

Comment: it's a single row